# Console.ReadLine not working it doesnt give the user an opportunity to type

Tags: c#

this is a simple program that converts human years to dog years but the  string Age = Console.ReadLine(); is not working the program doesnt give the user a chance to input instead the output is:

```
what is your age?
your age in dog years is:0
```

My code:

```
       using System;

        namespace Review
        {
          class Program
          {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
              Console.WriteLine("what is your age?");
              string Age = Console.ReadLine();  // this line is as if not read by the program
              int userAge = Convert.ToInt32(Age);
              Console.WriteLine("your age in dog years is:" + userAge/5);
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Try adding the line… `Console.ReadKey()` after the last line… `Console.WriteLine("your age in dog years is:" + userAge/5);` … without it the code simply exits and you will not see the result printed on the screen. IN other words, it prints the age, then closes the program. It will be to fast for you to see, that’s why you want the extra “read” to stop the code from exiting.

Answer (score 0):

It's working on my machine.
But you have to be careful with divide expression.
In case the UserAge is 4, it will return 0.
Please use double data types:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("what is your age?");
        string Age = Console.ReadLine();  // this line is as if not read by the program

        int userAge = Convert.ToInt32(Age);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.WriteLine("userAge: " + userAge.ToString());
        
        double dogsAge = userAge / 5d;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("your age in dog years is:" + dogsAge);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
```

Console:

```
what is your age?  
4  
userAge: 4  
your age in dog years is:0,8
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working properly and there is no problem with it, you just can't see the result.
All you need is add a  `Console.ReadLine();` to the end of your code.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("what is your age?");
        string Age = Console.ReadLine();  // this line is as if not read by the program
        int userAge = Convert.ToInt32(Age);
        Console.WriteLine("your age in dog years is:" + userAge / 5);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```